# On ios, in ionic hybrid app, how to bypass certificate check (using self-signed certificates)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate

My ionic/cordova app now gives errors when used with HTTPS backend

```
`The certificate for this server is invalid`
```

I am in my development environment, use self-signed certificates, and use IP address to connect with the backend.

I examined the certificate using `openssl s_client` and it looks valid. As a matter of fact I am able to use the same backend with android version of this hybrid app.

Is there some `plist` or other `Xcode` setting to accept a self-signed certificate or ignore this test all together - similar to `NSAppTransportSecurity::NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` setting?

--EDIT

I have `<access origin="*"/>` in my `config.xml` file.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you found solution to this issue for android dev environment?

Comment: From my experience - Android does not have this issue at all (at least with Android 5.0).

Answer (score 4):

You can add this at the end of AppDelegate.m, but just for testing purposes, you should remove it before releasing the app, apple might not approve the app if it contains that code

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

You can also check some workaround [here too !](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Comment: This works for trusted certificates that don't comply the new apple ATS requeriments, or for http connections, but for self signed certificates you have to use the code on my answer.